# Protect content in php (DRM)

Tags: php, drm

I searched for a way to make j2me games and images etc ....

DRM protected when these media are downloaded,so they can't be sent or copied to other devices
I tried to do this with php ,but i didn't succeed.

Is there a tutorial or a document that will help me.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: I do not see what PHP has to do with DRM protected media, at least not directly. You will need to elaborate what you are doing exactly, and what kind of media you are looking to distribute

Comment: The php is the script that allow users to get content ,so i need to set the drm headers or something that will make the content DRM protected using php.

Comment: You will, most likely, not succeed. Big companies like Ubisoft and Microsoft are working *very* hard to achieve exactly such functionality...and they fail every single time.

To be honest, I wouldn't bother with DRM and instead invest the energy and time into the games, so that they get *worth* buying...I mean, if you want to sell them, if you just want to prevent people from copying them, yes, there are *possibilities* (and there are ways to circumvent them). But I wouldn't bother.

Comment: I know this ,but our users not so smart and don't know how to broke the drm (i know there is many tools ).And this mean the mobile manufactures should stop make DRM support devices ,but they still do that.

Comment: @ibmkhd you are still not specifying what kind of content you are sending to where

Comment: The content are jars images and audio files,the user will login to the system from his mobile click buy and download the content.the php script read the file and then send it to the user.i need to add the drm header or the drm file at this moment.

Comment: @ibmkhd: I thing you misunderstand what DRM is. DRM is not a file or header you can send. DRM are technical measures *on the user device* to prevent certain operations. So you need to modify your jar, your images and your audio files to fit into these measures which are already in place *on the device* (f.e. using wma files) or you implement new ones. You can brand your jar files so that they will only work on that device, you can use wma files which can have a very strict DRM...but for images, you're out of luck except if you want to implement your own DRM measures (see my comment above).

Comment: After so many years I wanted to point something out.  The OP states in an earlier comment, `but our users not so smart and don't know how to broke the drm.`  This isn't the point.  All it takes is ***one*** user who knows how to do it and your broken files are available to everyone on the Internet for free.  The generally honest people not practiced in the art of programming aren't the problem --- it's the handful of unprincipled programmers that ruin everything for everyone.

Answer (score 5):

> The php is the script that allow users to get content ,so i need to set the drm headers or something that will make the content DRM protected using php

This is possible, but way more complicated than just setting some headers. Online music stores have a huge server infrastructure running for "activating" DRM protected content. To achieve this is not a trivial task.

Many on-line music stores have abandoned DRM, and have returned to selling unprotected MP3 files because DRM measures have turned out so unpopular. DRM is viewed by many as a failed undertaking.

Comment: I need the simplest solution just to disallow users to send content using blue-tooth i tried this on DRM-support mobile but it didn't work header('x-drm: noforward');

Answer (score 1):

Where is your PHP? Server-side? Then it is nothing different from any other DRM service - there's limitless possibilities to obscure content and it doesn't matter what language you use.

If you plan to make client-side player in PHP for some reason, then you're voluntarily making job of analyzing your "security through obscurity" (all DRM falls in this category, no exception) much easier, because PHP, being dynamic language, is much easier to read than compiled code.